# scrape a list of links found in a search result

Tags: python, hyperlink, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape search results from a library page. But since I want more than just the book titles, I want the script to open every search result and scrape the detailed site for more information.
What I have so far is the following:

```
    import bs4 as bs
    import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
    from http.cookiejar import CookieJar
    from bs4 import Comment


    cj = CookieJar()
    basisurl = 'http://mz-villigst.cidoli.de/index.asp?stichwort=hans'
    #just took any example page similar to the one i have in mind

    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
    p = opener.open(basisurl)

    for mednrs in soup.find_all(string=lambdatext:isinstance(text,Comment)):
    #and now when i do [0:] it gives me the medianumbers and i can create the links like this:

           links = 'http://mz-villigst.cidoli.de/index.asp?MEDIENNR=' + mednrs[10:17]
```

My main question now is: how can I get it to give me a list (like this: ["1", "2"]...) that I then can go through?

Comment: I don't understand your current code. What is `comments`?

Comment: sorry i meant mednrs instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list and append to it inside the loop:

```
links = []
for mednrs in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    link = 'http://mz-villigst.cidoli.de/index.asp?MEDIENNR=' + mednrs[10:17]
    links.append(link)
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
links = ['http://mz-villigst.cidoli.de/index.asp?MEDIENNR=' + mednrs[10:17]
         for mednrs in soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))]
```